# Reading line by line from a text file with sentences in Python and assigning it a value

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm working on a Machine Learning model that classifies a given line as belonging to a particular novel. The data set contains xtrain.txt, ytrain.txt. Each line in xtrain.txt comes from a different novel. The corresponding novel ids are specified in ytrain.txt. I'm trying to train the data from xtrain.txt and ytrain.txt

xtrain.txt contains lines of sentences. The problem I'm facing is how to read each line in xtrain.txt and assign it to a value in python so that I can train the data sets.

I hope to get some help here.

Comment: You're looking for [`open('file', 'mode')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: I managed to open the file using fin = open("xtrain.txt",encoding="utf8"). Now I'm not sure how to read each line from 'fin' and assign it to a value. I need a value for each line as it corresponds to a novel number in "ytrain.txt". Once I have it I can train the data

Comment: `with open("xtrain.txt",encoding="utf8") as f: data = f.read().splitlines()` now data is a list which contain your data's lines.

Comment: thanks. Would it be now possible to call the list line by line. Say if I want if I want to print the first line from data ? Can I use something like data[1,:]

Comment: You can iterate through the data list, or slice it and do whatever you want with this list.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked

Comment: @Krish I am working on the same problem. Where did you find this problem like in any book or website. And do you have a solution ? Which model did you use ?